# window.location result is null

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom, firebase-realtime-database

I want to build a website which returns products from a database and when click on See More, should return product details from server in another html page. The problem is that when I click See More, productID%20=%20null :(.
productDetails = second html page.
productDetails = div - in index.html where products are returned from server

```
<script>
var productsUrlList = 'https://finalonlineshop.firebaseio.com/.json';
async function getProductsFromServer() {
    var productsResponse = await fetch(productsUrlList)
    var products = await productsResponse.json();
    return products;
}

async function showProducts(productsPromise) {
    var products = await productsPromise;
    var generatedHTML = '';
    var productsIDs = Object.keys(products);
    productsIDs.forEach(productID => {
        var product = products[productID];
        generatedHTML += getGeneratedHTMLForProduct(productID, product);
    });
    document.getElementById('categories').innerHTML = generatedHTML;
}

function getGeneratedHTMLForProduct(productID, product) {
    var generatedHTML = `
        <div id = categoriesDiv>
            <img class = "categoryImage" src = ${product.Image} />
            <div class = "categoryName">${product.Name}</div>
            <div class = "categoryPrice">$ ${product.Price}</div>
            <br>
            <button id = "seeMore" onclick = "seeMore('${productID}')">See 
    more</button>
        </div>
    `;
    return generatedHTML;
}

function seeMore (productID) {
    window.location = `./productDetails.html?productID = ${productID}`;//issue
}
function getProductIDFromUrl () {
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var productID = params.get('productID');
return productID;
}

async function getDetailsFromServer(productID) {
var detailsResponse = await fetch(`https://finalonlineshop.firebaseio.com/Products/details/${productID}.json`);
var details = await detailsResponse.json();
return details;
}

async function seeDetails(detailsPromise) {
var details = await detailsPromise;
var generatedHTML = `
    <div id = "detailsAboutProduct">
        <img src = "${details.Image}" /> //Cannot read property "Image" of null
        <div>${details.Name}</div>
        <div>${details.Details}</div>
        <div>$ ${details.Price}</div>
        <div>${details.Qty}</div>
        <button id = "addToCart" onclick = "addToCart();">Add to 
    cart</button>
    </div>
`;
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = generatedHTML;
}

</script>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(productIDs)` show in `showProducts`?

Comment: not an object, as I'm debugging now. sorry for the low answer

Comment: `Object.keys()` should always return an array. Are there any null values in the array?

Comment: productsIDs:(9) ["Apple", "Beats", "Dell", "HP", "Huawei", "Iphone", "PlayStation IV", "Samsung", "Smart TV"]

Comment: the issue is in async function getDetailsFromServer()..... I get "details = null" on debugging

Comment: When I go to `https://finalonlineshop.firebaseio.com/Products/details/Apple.json` the response is `"null"`.

Comment: This seems like a problem with the finalonlineshop.firebaseio.com API, or you're not using the correct URL.

Answer (score 1):

get rid of the spaces around the `=` in the URL, that gets encoded as `%20`. You should also use `encodeURIComponent()` to escape any special characters in the product ID.

```
function seeMore (productID) {
    window.location = `./productDetails.html?productID=${encodeURIComponent(productID)}`;
}
```

Comment: Ok, no more null (thanks fot the tip), but still has a bug I think. please see https://vimeo.com/user28681679/review/288206213/40a212f9cf

Comment: I passed that. Now I get the productID=Apple, but it doesn't return the generatedHTML and when debug, I get "Cannot read property "Image" of null" - please see code lines added above.

Answer (score 0):

Your query to your firebase app seems to be wrong.

you are fetching : `https://finalonlineshop.firebaseio.com/Products/details/${productID}.json`
which return `null`

but you have to fetch: `https://finalonlineshop.firebaseio.com/${productID}.json`
instead and it will return the right object